# How to integrate knoll to soil?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I want to add some knolls onto a ground surface by using textures. Currently it looks terrible and I don't know how to integrate it properly.

What is the best procedure to do this? At the moment the stones do not look integrated into the knoll, there is a sharp border around it and it does not look natural.

I would like to use the bump map of the stone texture and then to texture paint over this bump with the sand texture stamp. How can I realize this in blender?

Additionally I want to work in Cycles. Does it make sense to create the textures in Blender Internal mode at first and then add the created texture to a material in Cycles mode?

I suggest this method because the handling of texturing is much easier in Blender Internal than in Cycles.

The current picture is like this:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/how-to-have-a-nice-visual-join-between-two-colliding-meshes

Answer (score -1):

Using cycles textures with an image you can take advantage of the `true displace` feature available with the `experimental feature set`

[image]

[image]

What this does is using a `musgrave` as factor for mixing both color and displacement textures

[image]