# How to add 2 organic meshes in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling a character for an project I'm working on and decided to make separate meshes for the body and legs. I decided to join them together after doing the basic modeling for each and can't seem to get them to look, well, normal.This is what I have so far.[image: What I have]

The problem[image: The problem][image: Second]

Comment: "Normal" is the key word here. [flip the normals](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12165/2217) for the leg object.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32325/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14774/599